# Calling tkFileDialog without opening a parent window

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to call `tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` without opening a parent tk window? This is annoying and (for me) goes unresponsive when I try to close it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to instantiate a root window, but you can hide it programmatically.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() # hide root

path = askdirectory()
root.mainloop()
```